# Creating subgroups in R

Tags: r

I'm am really new to R and am having some difficulties.
I have a giant table with more than 5000 rows and one of the columns is weight.
I am trying to create smaller tables with one having all subjects weighing less than 500g, the next with all subject weighing between 500 and 1000g and so on.
It seems like a relatively simple process but I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share a reproducible example. You can use `dput(head(df, 10)))` where `df` is the name of your dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset your data:

**Illustrative data**:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  subject = LETTERS[1:10],
  weight = sample(1:1000, 10)
)
```

**Solution**:

To create a subset for subjects with less than or equal to 500 weight:

```
df[df$weight <= 500, ]
```

**Result**:

```
df[df$weight <= 500, ]
   subject weight
1        A    288
3        C    409
6        F     46
10       J    453
```

Comment: Thank You! 
If i do this I get the following error:

Fehler in `[.data.frame`(nurgewicht, nurgewicht$`Geburtsgewicht in g` <=  : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Have you used the comma `,` after the weight and preceding the closing square bracket `]`? That is, this part: `<= 500, ]`. For ppl to be able to help you it is important that you show, in some way or other, what your data looks like and how it is structured.

Comment: I did not. Now it works !! Thank You so so much and have a nice day!

Comment: Do feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the green tick mark if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: And in case you need to define a range, such as **between 200 and 500**, use '&', building on Chris's neat solution: `df[df$weight <= 500  & df$weight >= 200, ]`

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps here: splitting the data frame into tables, and displaying them. Here is one way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                 b=c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18), 
                 weight=c(500,1000,1500,500,1000,1500,500,1000,1500))

df %>% group_split(weight)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b weight
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     2    500
2     4     8    500
3     7    14    500

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b weight
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2     4   1000
2     5    10   1000
3     8    16   1000

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b weight
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     3     6   1500
2     6    12   1500
3     9    18   1500
```

Once the data frame is split, you can display results in different ways, such as HTML output:

```
library(knitr)
> df %>% group_split(weight) %>% kable()

|  a|  b| weight|
|--:|--:|------:|
|  1|  2|    500|
|  4|  8|    500|
|  7| 14|    500|

|  a|  b| weight|
|--:|--:|------:|
|  2|  4|   1000|
|  5| 10|   1000|
|  8| 16|   1000|

|  a|  b| weight|
|--:|--:|------:|
|  3|  6|   1500|
|  6| 12|   1500|
|  9| 18|   1500|
```

Or you can send the output to data formatting routines, e.g. `df %>% group_split(weight) %>% regulartable() %>% autofit()` from `library(flextable)`.

Comment: If it works for you, be sure to click to accept it :) Thanks